# updating database update

Tags: php, html, sql

I am having trouble getting the database to update. Is there something wrong with my sql update statement? I checked the sql statement and it says that there were no records in the database. I am not sure what to do.

```
<!-- template for mySql database access. -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>CRUD</title>
          <link href="/sandvig/mis314/assignments/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       </head>
       <div class="pageContainer centerText">
          <h3>CRUD (Create, Read, Update, & Delete) Database</h3>
          <?php
          //include database connection
          include("DatabaseConnection2.php");

          //connect to database
          $link = fConnectToDatabase();

          //Retrieve parameters from querystring and sanitize
          $nameF = fCleanString($link, $_GET['nameF'], 15);
          $nameL = fCleanString($link, $_GET['nameL'], 15);
          $deleteID = fCleanNumber($_GET['deleteID']);
          $updateID = fCleanNumber($_GET['updateID']);
          $updateID2 = fCleanNumber($_GET['updateID2']);



           //Populate Textbox  
          if (!empty($updateID)) {
             $sql = "SELECT NameL, NameF
                     FROM customertbl
                     WHERE custID  = '$updateID'";
              mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die('Delete error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

             $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
                  or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
             $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
             $strFName2 = $row[NameF];
             $strLName2= $row[NameL];





          }




          ?>
          <hr>
          <form class="formLayout">
             <div class="formGroup">
                <label>First name:</label>
                <input name="nameF" type="text" autofocus value="<? echo $strFName2; ?>">
             </div>
             <div class="formGroup">
                <label>Last name:</label>
                <input name="nameL" type="text"  value="<? echo $strLName2; ?>">
             </div>
             <div class="formGroup">
                <label> </label>
                <button>Submit</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="updateID2" value="<? echo  $updateID; ?>">
             </div>
          </form>
          <?php




        //Update
          if (!empty($updateID2))
          {

             $sql = "UPDATE customertbl
                     SET NameL = '$strFName2', NameF ='$strLName2'
                     WHERE custID = '$updateID2' ";
             mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die('Insert error: ' . mysqli_error($link));


          }    


          //Insert
          if (!empty($nameF) && !empty($nameL)) {
             $sql = "Insert into customertbl (NameL, NameF)
                    VALUES ('$nameL', '$nameF')";
             mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die('Insert error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
          }

          //Delete
          if (!empty($deleteID)) {
             $sql = "Delete from customertbl WHERE CustID= '$deleteID' ";
             mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die('Delete error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
          }
          //List records
          $sql = 'SELECT custID, NameF, NameL
                    FROM customertbl order by custID';




          //$result is an array containing query results
          $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
                  or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

          echo "<p>" . mysqli_num_rows($result) . " records in the database</p>";
          ?>
          <table class="simpleTable">
             <tr>
                <th>Cust. ID</th>
                <th>F. Name</th>
                <th>L. Name</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Update</th>
             </tr>
             <?php
             // iterate through the retrieved records
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                //Field names are case sensitive and must match
                //the case used in sql statement
                $custID = $row['custID'];
                echo "<tr>
                         <td>$custID</td>
                         <td>$row[NameF]</td>
                         <td>$row[NameL]</td>
                         <td><a href='?deleteID=$custID'>Delete</a></td>
                         <td><a href='?updateID=$custID'>Update</a></td>
                     </tr>";
             }
             ?> 
          </table>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please show us the error you are getting and to which line of your code it belongs. That makes it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: I am not getting an error I am just not getting the outcome I want. When I click the update hyperlink, it then populates the textboxes. You should be able to edit the textboxes, and then when you click submit. it updates the database fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending code block

```
    //Update
      if (!empty($updateID2))
      {

         $sql = "UPDATE customertbl
                 SET NameL = '$strFName2', NameF ='$strLName2'
                 WHERE custID = '$updateID2' ";
         mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die('Insert error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
      }
```

makes references to variables `$strFName2` and `$strLName2` which are variables that are only populated conditionally.

```
       //Populate Textbox  
      if (!empty($updateID)) {
         $sql = "SELECT NameL, NameF
                 FROM customertbl
                 WHERE custID  = '$updateID'";
          mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die('Delete error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

         $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
              or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
         $strFName2 = $row[NameF];
         $strLName2= $row[NameL];
      }
```

Since the variables `$strFName2` and `$strLName2` are undefined during the `UPDATE` SQL query, you're not seeing the desired results.

The query should reference `$nameF` and `$nameL` since those variables are always defined (not contained within a conditional) and the form inputs use `nameF` and `nameL` in their name attributes.

```
$sql = "UPDATE customertbl
    SET NameL = '$nameF', NameF ='$nameL'
    WHERE custID = '$updateID2';";
```

You also need to fix your `DELETE` query to reference the column `custID` and not `CustID` as it appears your schema uses the former.

```
$sql = "Delete from customertbl WHERE custID= '$deleteID' ";
```

Comment: I fixed those issues. But Im still having a problem. Everytime I update, it is assigning it to a new id. it is not updating the id field i want it to

Comment: @TimothyWong That's because the `INSERT` code block will always be run because it isn't contained within a conditional which restricts it to only run when `$updateID2` is empty.